# MySql PHP script is giving question marks for columns wiht cyrillic alphabet

Tags: php, mysql, wampserver

I have tried 
header('Content-type: text/plain; charset=utf-8');

but still I have the same problem when I run the script in my local browser.
The collation is utf8_general_ci
Any solutions ?

[Script output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oeO0b.jpg)

[Database structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6r4dG.jpg)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [UTF-8 all the way through](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through)

Comment: There are also MySQL client and connection properties for character encoding. You are wading into one of the most annoying aspects of the universe right now.

Comment: Oh, I will try the miken32 link.. Why the most annoying things are happening to me, I have just started to use mySql and PHP :(